# How to make the dash shell run some commands meant for sh (bash)?

Tags: linux, shell, pycharm, sh, linux-mint

**IN BRIEF**: I have `mysql_config` installed on Linux Mint 19.  It runs fine when typed into the shell, or run as `bash mysql_config`.  BUT it fails when issued as `sh mysql_config` or `dash mysql_config`

**BACKGROUND:**

On Linux Mint 19, I installed `mysql_config` with the command `sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`

It seems to start fine when typed into the shell, or run as `bash mysql_config`.

**MY OVER-ARCHING GOAL:**

Inside PyCharm, I'm using its native support of *pipenv* to install a series of Packages listed in a `Pipfile` document.  It all works like a dream for all Packages - EXCEPT that it chokes on `mysqlclient` (ironically, I have no such problem on a parallel build on Windows 7!  But on Linux Mint, it chokes.)

The error file from the failed installation of the `mysqlclient` Package includes statements like:

```
"/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found', '    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found', '    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found',"
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Presumably, the complaint from the installer stems from a failure to run `/bin/sh mysql_config`

Indeed, as stated at the beginning, `/bin/sh mysql_config` FAILS, with the message: `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open mysql_config`

If I do `ls -l /bin/sh`, it shows: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May 25 00:31 /bin/sh -> dash`

And, indeed, I found a reference saying that *"in the last couple of years Debian (and Ubuntu) decided to switch the system shell from bash to dash"*.

So, I'm on Linux Mint, and i**t looks like my system shell is `dash`... while the installer is presumably expecting `bash` (as I mentioned `dash mysql_config` works.)**  Any recommendation?  Thanks, Linux gurus!

Comment: Um. `/bin/sh mariadb_config` looks for a file in your current directory named `mariadb_config`; if you want it to do the same thing it would do if you invoked `mariadb_config` *on a command line*, that would be `/bin/sh -c 'mariadb_config'`; the `-c` is necessary to make it expect a command instead of a filename.

Comment: Bigger picture, though -- bash, dash, and every other shell invoke external commands **the exact same way**, using an `execve()`-family syscall to tell the operating system to replace the current process with one having a given name and argument list, after `fork()`ing off a subcommand. It's extremely unlikely that your problem has anything whatsoever to do with the shell selection.

Comment: Anyhow: If `dash mysql_config` works, then we know `mysql_config` can't have bashisms. Frankly, this looks more like a hardcoded (and invalid) interpreter location, or a `PATH` that doesn't include your script location in the context of the postinstall script, or some other variant on the above (like an interpreter that requires a shared library that isn't installed). Either way, the problem extends beyond the four corners of the code included in the question, into the decisions made by the people building Linux Mint packaging.

Comment: Doubling back, though: As I said in my very first comment, `/bin/sh mysql_config` is **expected** to fail, unless you run it in a directory that contains a file named `mysql_config`. Running `bash mysql_config` will fail the exact same way, for the exact same reason, if not run in a directory containing a thusly-named script itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : you're right that the "-c" option restores functionality.  Indeed: `/bin/sh -c mysql_config` works, while `/bin/sh mysql_config` didn't work without the -c. 
So, it seems that dash (the shell invoked by /bin/sh in my system) needs a "-c" while bash is perfect happy without?

Comment: ...well, I'll be damned -- turns out bash *does* execute a PATH lookup when given an invalid filename with no `/`. So yes, what you've got here is a test that depends on bash doing something very nonstandard. However, I doubt that your package is really doing the same thing -- which is to say, I'm 99% certain that the test is a red herring.

Comment: ...anyhow, if you want to provide some certainty on the point, a great place to start would be to install [sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig), and generate a trace of the `execve()` syscalls that take place while your (failing) installer is running. If that shows your package installer running `sh mysql_config`, we'll have our answer (though my expectation is that we'll see something a bit different from that).

Comment: That's an idea, thanks @CharlesDuffy!  
But, first, I'll try to bypass PyCharm and run `pipenv` directly.  I wonder if the PyCharm installer is doing something wrong.  But  all other Packages get installed just fine...  I have the newest version of PyCharm - and never before has it given me any Package installation grief, in the years I've been using it...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, it might be uncommon that bash performs a path search under the circumstances, but it is not nonstandard.  POSIX [specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) for this case (neither `-c` nor `-s` given) that "If the file is not in the current working directory, the implementation may perform a search for an executable file using the value of PATH, as described in Command Search and Execution."

Comment: Granted, the behavior is *permitted* by the standard, but it isn't *required*; so any program depending on it is needlessly nonportable.